# how i can select records with varbinary type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have table in my database that has two column namely data and length.
I declare data as a `VARBINARY(MAX)` and suppose the table has a record with length equal to 5 and data = `0x23 0x00 0x12 0x45 0x34`.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbInputFile] (
  [InputFileID] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
  [Filename] [varchar](512) NULL, 
  [Filesize] [bigint] NULL, 
  [Content] [varbinary](max) NULL
);
```

The question:

Is it possible to search (with a `SELECT` query) to find records that has `0x00 0x12` in their data column?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: i am guessing it to be `sql server`

Comment: Do you have the **Data Definition** at hand (`create table` statement)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbInputFile]
(
 [InputFileID] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
 [Filename] [varchar](512) NULL,
 [Filesize] [bigint] NULL,
 [Content] [varbinary](max) NULL,
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL query. Inner table contains test data with binary data type. `0x48` is the data that I'm searching in the `test_col1` column.

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM
    (SELECT CAST('Hello' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS test_col1,
            CAST('World' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS test_col2) AS T
     WHERE CAST(test_col1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%' + CAST(0x48 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tbInputFile 
where convert(varchar(max), content,2) like '%00%' 
   or convert(varchar(max), content,2) like '%12%'
```